# What is the format of the result coming back from facebook payments reports API?

Tags: php, facebook

i am using PHP with symfony 2, trying to get the facebook payment reports to work.
i sent a request to https://paymentreports.facebook.com/[company id]/report?
with the relevant parameters,  and i do get a response, however , in addition
to just having the csv file name (which is what i expected) i get a lot of "junk"
(like weird ASCII characters from other languages etc.).

what is the format of this result and how do i filter out the junk?
in the end, how do i take this file name and get the csv file out it? make another http request?

thanks

Comment: anyone? did anyone managed to use this new API and can post a code sample in PHP?

Comment: did you take a look @ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/developer_reports_api/